# YII2, ошибка при создании миграции

Tags: yii2

> php yii migrate/create create_article_table
>   Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.13)
>
> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049]
>   Unknown database 'yii2basic'' in
>   C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php:597

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(943): yii\db\Connection->open()                                                      
#1 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php(930): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()                                              
#2 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(243): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()                                                  
#3 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1062): yii\db\Command->prepare(true)                                                    
#4 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(386): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)                                   
#5 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\Schema.php(320): yii\db\Command->queryAll()                                                   
#6 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\mysql\Schema.php(111): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findColumns(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))                 
#7 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(660): yii\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema('migration')                                  
#8 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php(173): yii\db\Schema->getTableMetadata('{{%migration}}', 'schema', true)                  
#9 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\MigrateController.php(334): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%migration}}', true)  
#10 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController.php(631): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigr
ationNameLimit()                                                                                                                                                
#11 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionCreate('create_article_...')                                                      
#12 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)                                         
#13 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)                                 
#14 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(135): yii\base\Controller->runAction('create', Array)                          
#15 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller->runAction('create', Array)                              
#16 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/create', Array)                     
#17 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/create', Array)             
#18 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))        
#19 C:\php\OpenServer\domains\flatron\yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()                                                                                      
#20 {main}
```

Comment: ну ошибка `Unknown database 'yii2basic''` как бы намекает на что-то

Comment: если не секрет, то на что?

Comment: что вы знаете о словах  `Unknown`  и `database`?

Comment: неизвестная база данных

Comment: ну вот как бы и вот) нужна правильная база

Comment: какой замечательный ответ, спасибо за помощь, что б я без вас делал

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема. ты не можешь указать корректную бд?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в конфиге указать имя созданной БД, к которой создается миграция.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема. Оказывается в папке config в файле db.php по умолчанию прописана эта база данных yii2base. Я просто создал эту базу в phpMyAdmin  с именем как указано yii2base и все прекрасно заработало.
Предполагаю, что можно было вначале поменять имя в config/db.php на имя которое нужно и создать базу с нужным именем а не yii2base.